# Return lastIndexOf exact word in a string

Tags: javascript

I want to find the last index of an exact word in a string but I can't make the code work correctly:

```js
var a = 'foo';
let speechResult = 'I went to foo the foobar and ordered foo foot football.'
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + a + '\\b');
console.log(speechResult.search(regex));
```

I've tried :

```
speechResult.lastIndexOf(regex)
```

But it didn't work.

Note: there are two `foo`s in the string and my code always returns the first one. Using `lastIndexOf(a)` alone returns the index of football, rather than the index of the last standalone foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative lookahead for `'\\b' + a + '\\b'` anywhere after the match:

```js
var a = 'foo';
let speechResult = 'I went to foo the foobar and ordered foo foot footbal.'
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + a + '\\b(?!.*\\b' + a + '\\b)');
console.log(speechResult.search(regex));
```

Perhaps more readably, with `String.raw` (allowing you to not double-escape the backslashes, and to interpolate with `${}` rather than `' + b + '`):

```js
var a = 'foo';
let speechResult = 'I went to foo the foobar and ordered foo foot footbal.'
var regex = new RegExp(String.raw`\b${a}\b(?!.*\b${a}\b)`);
console.log(speechResult.search(regex));
```

Answer (score 1):

With lastIndexOf you can do that:

```
var foo='foo';
var speechResult='I went to foo the foob...';
var index=speechResult.lastIndexOf(foo);
console.log(index);
```

Comment: It returns foob not foo